# How to perform a left join on two pandas dataframes for a specific use case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

Example Data:
Here is a simplified representation of my dataframes:

My first dataframe(df1) is like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | 3 | 4 |
| 11 | 22 | aa | 33 | 44 |
| 111 | 222 | aaa |  |  |

And my second dataframe(df2) is something like:

| col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 4 |
| aa | 332 | 442 |
| aaa | 333 | 444 |

And i want my merged dataframe (result_df) to look something like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | 3 | 4 |
| 11 | 22 | aa | 33 | 44 |
| 11 | 22 | aa | 332 | 442 |
| 111 | 222 | aaa | 333 | 444 |

I attempted to use the pd.merge function with a left join:

`result_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col3', how='left')`

result_df looks like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4_x | col5_x | col4_y | col5_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 11 | 22 | aa | 33 | 44 | 332 | 442 |
| 111 | 222 | aaa |  |  | 333 | 444 |

I'm trying to understand why the resulting dataframe has additional columns and how to achieve the desired output. Any help or insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proposition with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)/[`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html) :

```
mg = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="col3", how="left")

grps = {c: [f"{c}_{s}" for s in ["x", "y"]]
        for c in df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).drop("col3")}
        
out = pd.lreshape(mg, grps).drop_duplicates().convert_dtypes()
```

*NB: The loop is really optional here and can be replaced with a hardcoded mapping of the common columns (except the one to join on, i.e, `col3`) between both DataFrames :*

```
grps = {'col4': ['col4_x', 'col4_y'], 'col5': ['col5_x', 'col5_y']}
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   col1  col2 col3  col4  col5
0     1     2    a     3     4
1    11    22   aa    33    44
3    11    22   aa   332   442
4   111   222  aaa   333   444

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another alternative using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), filling NaNs and then dropping duplicates:

```py
out = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(['col3'])
out[['col1', 'col2']] = out[['col1', 'col2']].ffill()
out[['col4', 'col5']] = out[['col4', 'col5']].bfill()
out = (out
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
    .convert_dtypes()
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2 col3  col4  col5
0     1     2    a     3     4
1    11    22   aa    33    44
2    11    22   aa   332   442
3   111   222  aaa   333   444
```

Answer (score 2):

This feeds off @Timeless logic of merging followed by a reshape:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1
.merge(df2, on = 'col3')
# this is from janitor
# this keeps only the part of the column
# that matches .value as header
.pivot_longer(
    index='col[123]', 
    names_to = '.value', 
    names_pattern=r"(.+)_", 
    dropna=True)
.drop_duplicates()
.convert_dtypes()
)

   col1  col2 col3  col4  col5
0     1     2    a     3     4
1    11    22   aa    33    44
3    11    22   aa   332   442
4   111   222  aaa   333   444
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there's a better way to do this but currently my strategy is to find all rows that exist in df1 but not in df2 and then concat those rows to df2 and then perform a left join of df1 and df2

my first dataframe (df1) is:

```py
    data1 = {'col1': [1, 11, 111],
             'col2': [2, 22, 222],
             'col3': ['a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
             'col4': [3, 33, pd.NA],
             'col5': [4, 44, pd.NA]}

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

This gives me:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | 3 | 4 |
| 11 | 22 | aa | 33 | 44 |
| 111 | 222 | aaa |  |  |

Now I'll drop col1 and col2

```py
    df1_last3cols = df1.drop(['col1',"col2"], axis=1)
```

So now my df1_last3cols looks like :

| col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 4 |
| aa | 33 | 44 |
| aaa |  |  |

My df2 looks like:

```py
    data2 = {'col3': ['a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
             'col4': [3, 332, 333],
             'col5': [4, 442, 444]}
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

| col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 4 |
| aa | 332 | 442 |
| aaa | 333 | 444 |

Then I extract the rows which come from the left dataframe(df1_last3cols) and concat with df2.

```py
    merged_df = pd.merge(df1_last3cols, df2, on=['col3', 'col4', 'col5'], how='left', indicator=True)
    
    # Filter rows where the _merge column indicates differences
    diff_df = merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] == 'left_only']
    
    # Drop the _merge column from the result
    diff_df = diff_df.drop(columns=['_merge'])
    
    #adding diff_df to df2
    result_df = pd.concat([diff_df, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

So now my result_df looks like:

| col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 33 | 44 |
| aaa |  |  |
| a | 3 | 4 |
| aa | 332 | 442 |
| aaa | 333 | 444 |

And then I implement left join once again but this time with df1 and result_df.

```py
    merged_df = pd.merge(df1, result_df, on="col3", how = "left")
    merged_df.drop(["col4_x","col5_x"], inplace=True, axis= 1)
    merged_df.rename(columns={'col4_y': 'col4', 'col5_y': 'col5'})
    merged_df.dropna(inplace=True)
    merged_df
```

After some cleaning and changing col names. Voila!

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | 3 | 4 |
| 11 | 22 | aa | 33 | 44 |
| 11 | 22 | aa | 332 | 442 |
| 111 | 222 | aaa | 333 | 333 |

If someone has an elegant solution feel free to post, any kind of improvement is greatly appritiated.